# In Xcode7 when I new a folder in the project base folder To the project,then the folder is blue

Tags: xcode

when you new a group we can not find a real folder in the project,So we new a folder and add it as files to the project.But this time in Xcode7 I AddFileTo my project ,the folder is blue .

Comment: I read your question 3 times and I still don't get what your problem nor the question is!?

Comment: He is importing reference to the folder to his xcode project. That is his issue.

Comment: thinks,yes ,it's the issue,the correct display of the folder is yellow,when the fold is blue ,the reference is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the folder as reference. when you add the folder, make sure you check "Create groups"....not "Create folder reference". See the following Screenshot.

[image: screenshot]